# Android - Webservice error could not execute main

Tags: android, web-services

i'm trying to make my first android webservice and i'm having issues making a simple call.

I get the error located here `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope)`  Any help is welcomed

Here is the enitre code for my MainActivity.java

```
package com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://mysite.sytes.net:9040/";
    private final String URL = "http://mysite.sytes.net:9040/Math.asmx?";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://mysite.sytes.net:9040/Math.asmx?op=InsertComment";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "InsertComment";
    private String TAG = "PGGURU";
    private static String celcius;
    private static String fahren;
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Celcius Edit Control
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
        //Set Name
        celsiusPI.setName("NewComment");
        //Set Value
        celsiusPI.setValue("cell");
        //Set dataType
        celsiusPI.setType(String.class);
        //Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
        //Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            //Invole web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //Assign it to fahren static variable
            fahren = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("wawa",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error log

```
05-21 22:52:14.231  32163-32163/com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-21 22:52:34.483  32163-32163/com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3609)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17063)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3604)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17063)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
            at com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:99)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3604)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17063)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 22:52:34.523     616-1066/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice
05-21 22:52:34.523     616-1066/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.teachingperiod.android.testwebservice v1 (1.0)
05-21 22:52:34.523     616-1066/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: TestWebService
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 99

```
        Log.i("wawa",e.getMessage());
```

e.getMessage() is returning a null pointer. Change it to

```
        Log.i("wawa",e.getMessage() + "");
```

To ensure you don't send a null to the Log class.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity >
**http connection must execute another thread (not main thread)**

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        ....
        Log.i("wawa",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }.start();
}
```